# How to make Wordpress search prioritise page titles?

Tags: search

The standard search for Wordpress works, but doesn't seem too clever. If I search for 'tomato' and I have a page whose title is 'Tomato' I would expect that to come first in the results. However the results seem to be ordered by date published. So if a page/post mentions 'tomato' somewhere in the text, it will be first in the results if it was just published.

How would I make Wordpress prioritise page titles in the search?

(I'm using the Starkers theme)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the default Wordpress search with something more useful. As you have pointed out, the build-in search is very limited. So you're not the first one with this problem. I suggest the following two plugins:

- [Search API (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search/)
- [WordPress Sphinx Search Plugin (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-sphinx-plugin/)

The last one allows to weight between parts of a post. But keep in mind that it needs you to configure and make use of [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/), a free open-source SQL full-text search engine.